# Matching [STRING] between Param (...) block

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

If you look at the below code snippet, I'm trying to match all `[STRING]` that are inside the `Param ( ... )` block **ONLY**.

I've been at this for awhile and I just can't seem to find out how to do it. I tried to use lookaheads, lookbehinds, recursion and referencing capture groups.

What I currently have: `(?<=Param\(\s*\1|)(\[\w*\])`

Code:

```
Param(
    [STRING]$CustomerName,
    [STRING]$ClusterName,
)

[STRING]$CustomerName,
[STRING]$ClusterName,
```

What I want to achieve with a regex is to match all `[STRING]` if the first `[STRING]` also matches `Param (`.
And then continue matching until the closing brace `)` is found.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hVeb8R/1

I use javascript there as it seems to closely match expected functionality for C#.

Comment: What language or tool it is?

Comment: Ah sorry, it's C# .NET

Comment: You're so in luck. Try `(?<=Param\([^()]*)\[\w+]`. Based on your current requirements it does what you want. You shouldn't use it in regex101 however. It's .NET specific and regex101 doesn't support .NET. But in latest versions of Chrome by switching to javascript engine you'll see the expected output https://regex101.com/r/68KpvA/1

Comment: That does work! thank you! I'm confused though, I don't understand how this works, I can see the `^()` and understand that it's the opening and closing brace but how does the engine know that the match we want is in the middle of the braces? if that makes any sense?

Comment: Feel free to add this as the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: You need a lookahead, too, if you want to make sure the strings are inside parentheses, `@"(?<=Param\([^()]*)\[\w+](?=[^()]*\))"`. See [this .NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dParam%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%29%5c%5b%5cw%2b%5d%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%29&i=Param%28%0d%0a++++%5bSTRING%5d%24CustomerName%2c%0d%0a++++%5bSTRING%5d%24ClusterName%2c%0d%0a%29%0d%0a%5bSTRING%5d%24CustomerName%2c%0d%0a%5bSTRING%5d%24ClusterName%2c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET supports infinite repetitions in lookbehinds. A capability that is not very often found in RegEx engines world. By invoking that feature you can achieve the desired result using:

```
(?<=Param\([^()]*)\[\w+]
```

The pattern in lookbehind ensures that without going beyond a parenthesis a match on `Param(` should be found. `[^()]` means never match a parenthesis while looking back for `Param(`. That's almost it but if you want to do another check on `[STRING]` being followed by a closing parenthesis you have to append a positive lookahead like so:

```
(?<=Param\([^()]*)\[\w+](?=[^()]*\))
```

Using Chrome, see [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/68KpvA/1)

Comment: I have a new issue which is somewhat relevant to my question and your answer, but I can always post a new question or just fiddle around a bit more. If you look at this demo: https://regex101.com/r/qYtvmj/1 you'll see that `[STRING]` is no longer highlighted because something else is in the way that also has braces.

Comment: Never use a regex that you don't know exactly what it does. Your new requirement makes to be accomplished in more steps. Are you going to do a substitution?

Comment: I plan to use it for highlighting all of the types between [...] inside a Param block.

Comment: See: https://regex101.com/r/68KpvA/2 the last block of code has no highlights. I'm assuming this is the case because the lookbehind stops at the `parameter` line.

Comment: Try `(?m)(?<=Param\s*\(\s*(?:^(?!\s*(?:Param\s*\(|\))).*\s*)*)\[\w+]` but this is highly dependant on your current format and may break easily. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/tXAuTY/1

Comment: Thank you, I have modified as per my full requirement: https://regex101.com/r/tXAuTY/2